# R Conditional Replace/Trim with Fill (regex,gsub,gregexpr,regmatches)

Tags: regex, r, replace, trim

I have a question involving conditional replace.

I essentially want to find every string of numbers and, for every consecutive digit after 4, replace it with a space.

I need the solution to be vectorized and speed is essential.

Here is a working (but inefficient solution):

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=6, dimnames=list(c(), c("input","output"))), 
                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data[1,] <- c("STRING WITH 2 FIX(ES): 123456    098765  1111   ",NA)
data[2,] <- c(" PADDED STRING WITH 3 FIX(ES): 123456    098765  111111   ",NA)
data[3,] <- c(" STRING WITH 0 FIX(ES): 12        098     111   ",NA)
data[4,] <- c(NA,NA)
data[5,] <- c("1234567890",NA)
data[6,] <- c("   12345   67890    ",NA)

x2 <- data[,"input"]
x2

p1 <- "([0-9]+)"

m1 <- gregexpr(p1, x2,perl = TRUE)

nchar1 <- lapply(regmatches(x2, m1), function(x){
  if (length(x)==0){ x <- NA  } else ( x <- nchar(x))
  return(x) })

x3 <- mapply(function(match,length,text,cutoff) {
  temp_comb <- data.frame(match=match, length=length, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  for(i in which(temp_comb[,"length"] > cutoff))
  {
    before <- substr(text, 1, (temp_comb[i,"match"]-1))
    middle_4 <- substr(text, temp_comb[i,"match"], temp_comb[i,"match"]+cutoff-1)
    middle_space <-  paste(rep(" ", temp_comb[i,"length"]-cutoff),sep="",collapse="")
    after <-  substr(text, temp_comb[i,"match"]+temp_comb[i,"length"], nchar(text))
    text <- paste(before,middle_4,middle_space,after,sep="")
  }
  return(text)

},match=m1,length=nchar1,text=x2,cutoff=4)

data[,"output"] <- x3
```

Is there a better way?

I was looking at the help section for *regmatches* and there was a similar type question, but it was full replacement with blanks and not conditional.

I would have written some alternatives and benchmarked them but honestly I couldn't think of other ways to do this.

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

UPDATE

Fleck,

Using your way but making cutoff an input, I am getting an error for the NA case:

```
#replace numbers afther the 4th with spaces for those matches
zz<-lapply(regmatches(data$input, m), function(x,cutoff) {

    # x <- regmatches(data$input, m)[[4]]
    # cutoff <- 4

    mapply(function(x, n, cutoff){
      formatC(substr(x,1,cutoff), width=-n)
    }, x=x, n=nchar(x),cutoff=cutoff)

},cutoff=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with `gregexpr` and `regmatches`

```
#find all numbers with more than 4 digits
m <- gregexpr("\\d{5,}", data$input)

#replace numbers afther the 4th with spaces for those matches
zz<-lapply(regmatches(data$input, m), function(x) {
        mapply(function(x, n) formatC(substr(x,1,4), width=-n), x, nchar(x))
})

#combine with original values
data$output2 <- unlist(Map(function(a,b) paste0(a,c(b,""), collapse=""), 
    regmatches(data$input, m, invert=T), zz))
```

The different here is that it turns the `NA` value into `""`. We could add in other checks to prevent that or just turn all zero length strings into missing values at the end. I just didn't want to over-complicate the code with safety checks.

Comment: Thanks Flick.  I like this approach.

Comment: Flick, I am getting an error when I make cutoff dynamic:

Comment: Well, don't do that. Actually, I have no idea what you mean by that. What exactly did you change and what exactly is the error?

Comment: You are using `mapply` incorrectly. You can't just add `cutoff=cutoff` because that only has length one and `mappply` expects all parameters to have the same length. You'll have to add it with the `MoreArgs=` parameter. For example `MoreArgs=list(cutoff=cutoff)`. See `?mapply` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast approach with just one `gsub` command:

```
gsub("(?<!\\d)(\\d{4})\\d*", "\\1", data$input, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "STRING WITH 2 FIX(ES): 1234    0987  1111   "        
# [2] " PADDED STRING WITH 3 FIX(ES): 1234    0987  1111   "
# [3] " STRING WITH 0 FIX(ES): 12        098     111   "    
# [4] NA                                                    
# [5] "1234"                                                
# [6] "   1234   6789    "
```

The string `(?<!\\d)` is a negative lookahead: A position that is not preceded by a digit. The string `(\\d{4})` means *4 consecutive digits*. Finally, `\\d*` represents any number of digits. The part of the string that matches this regex is replaced by the first group (the first 4 digits).

---

An approach that does not change string length:

```
matches <- gregexpr("(?<=\\d{4})\\d+", data$input, perl = TRUE)
mapply(function(m, d) {
  if (!is.na(m) && m != -1L) {
    for (i in seq_along(m)) {
      substr(d, m[i], m[i] + attr(m, "match.length") - 1L) <- paste(rep(" ", attr(m, "match.length")[i]), collapse = "")
    }
  }
  return(d)
}, matches, data$input)

# [1] "STRING WITH 2 FIX(ES): 1234      0987    1111   "          
# [2] " PADDED STRING WITH 3 FIX(ES): 1234      0987    1111     "
# [3] " STRING WITH 0 FIX(ES): 12        098     111   "          
# [4] NA                                                          
# [5] "1234      "                                                
# [6] "   1234    6789     "
```

Comment: So you are actually shortening the string rather than replacing the extra numbers with spaces. I think this is different than what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Sven,  thanks for the help but your response isn't giving the same answers as mine. A couple differences I see: Row 1 there should be 6 spaces between 1234 and 0987 and row 4 has no trailing blanks.  I don't want to just remove the characters after 4, I want to replaces them with spaces so strings should be the same length after the replacement.

Comment: @Brad See the update. I did not test whether the approach is faster than yours.

Comment: Thanks Sven. Your makes complete sense

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in one line *(and one space for one digit)* with:

```
gsub("(?:\\G(?!\\A)|\\d{4})\\K\\d", " ", data$input, perl = TRUE)
```

details:

```
(?:        # non-capturing group: the two possible entry points
    \G     # either the position after the last match or the start of the string
    (?!\A) # exclude the start of the string position
  |        # OR
    \d{4}  # four digits
)          # close the non-capturing group
\K         # removes all on the left from the match result
\d         # a single digit
```

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: It's to forbid `\G` to match the start of the string. Because the entry point for the first match must be the second alternative (i.e. `\d{4}`), if I allow `\G` to match the start of the string and if there is a digit at the start of the string, the digit will be removed.